# How to Show Key in select dropdown in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, select

My JSON is :

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c2523d581c4c8c218d2392"),
    "aboutUs" : "Demo About Us." 
}

{
    "_id" : ObjectId("54c2523d581c4c8c218d2393"),
    "tutorial" : "Demo Tutorial." 
}
```

I want to show `"aboutUs"`, and `"tutorial"` in the dropdown, and on-change of select-dropdown get the corresponding value.

For example, if we select "aboutUs" then we get "Demo About Us".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If these are your only 2 options, then you should just hardcode them, since each key is unique to each object.

```
<select ng-model="selectedOption">
  <option value="aboutUs">Demo About Us<option>
  <option value="tutorial">Demo Tutorial<option>
</select>
```

If, otherwise, you could have an array of different options objects then you need a different way to represent your data. For example, like so:

```
$scope.selectOptions = [
   { 
      id: 123,
      key: "aboutUs",
      value: "Demo About Us",
   },
   { 
      id: 456,
      key: "tutorial",
      value: "Demo Tutorial",
   },
   // etc...
];
```

Then, you could create your `<select>` like so:

```
<div ng-model="selectedOption"
     ng-option="o.key as o.value for o in selectOptions">
</div>
```